# Change zedgraph pane background color

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is it possible to change the background color (white by default) of a zedgraph pane?

I tried changing the background color of the zedgraph element, but it doesn't give any visible result, background is still white:

```
ZedGraphControl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

And there doesn't seem to exist a `Color` or `BackColor` property on `ZedGraphControl.GraphPane`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
zg.GraphPane.Chart.Fill.Color = SystemColors.ControlText;
```

to change the background [only] of the chart.
If you want to change the background color the zedgraph except the chart, use

```
zg.GraphPane.Fill.Color = SystemColors.ControlText;
```

If you want to change the background color of everything in the zedgraph, use both:

```
zg.GraphPane.Chart.Fill.Color = SystemColors.ControlText;
zg.GraphPane.Fill.Color = SystemColors.ControlText;
```

EDIT: I know that you already solved your problem but I made this so if someone searches it, he can solve his problem quickly :)

Comment: I'll accept your answer because you are right, it will be more helpful for people having the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

```
myChart.GraphPane.Chart.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I would like to change the color of the `GraphPane`, not only the `Chart`. In your case, the background color around the chart (axies, legends) is still white.

Comment: Found what was missing: I have also to set:  

`myChart.GraphPane.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;` Noted as accepted even if it provides only the half of the answer ;) Thx

Answer (score 5):

`myChart.GraphPane.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;` will create a gradient fill started with black color. If you don't want to use gradient you should use -

`myChart.GraphPane.Chart.Fill.Brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black);`

Hope this will solve your problem.