# Change entire zedgraph background color

Tags: c#, zedgraph

My question has to do with an existing question: [Change zedgraph pane background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997690/change-zedgraph-pane-background-color)

However, I would like to change the entire pane, not just the chart. So far, I have this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZedGraph does have some quirks.

To change the color of both the chart and the pane

```
// This will do the area outside of the graphing area
GraphPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.FromArgb(222, 224, 212));
// This will do the area inside the graphing area
GraphPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.FromArgb(222, 224, 212));
```

Comment: thanks a lot. now i need to figure out for the axis, title, and x-y labels!

Comment: `GraphPane.XAxis.Color` etc // You might have to draw the scale yourself if you want it colored, I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: probably, nothing seemed to happen.  want it to be white though

Comment: Its not too hard to draw them yourself, and its worth the control you get.

Comment: I ended up doing this: GraphPane.Chart.Border.Color = Color.White;